# Transfer list of data from gridview to another page

Tags: c#, list, session, gridview

I have gridview look like this[image]

Any time user click on Bookmark button, I wanna send the ProgramID of that row to the List and transfer it to another page by using Session.But my gridview transfer the all programID, even though that ID existed in the list. What am I doing wrong?
This is the code for Bookmark button:

```
protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


   Button b = (Button)sender;      
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
    var ProgramID = row.FindControl("lblProgramID") as Label;
    string stringProgramID = ProgramID.Text;      
    List<string> bookmarkPrograms = (List<string>)Session["BookmarkProgram"];
    if (bookmarkPrograms == null)
        bookmarkPrograms = new List<string>();
    bookmarkPrograms.Add(stringProgramID);
    Session["BookmarkProgram"] = bookmarkPrograms;

}
```

And here is the code for the gridview in another page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> bookMarkPrograms = (List<string>)Session["BookmarkProgram"];

    GridView1.DataSource = bookMarkPrograms;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure about the flow of events. But if I get you correctly, you want the list to be constantly adding. You are doing

```
 Session["BookmarkProgram"] = bookmarkPrograms;
```

Which means that this variable is that specific value. But then if you do it again then this happens:

```
   List<string> bookmarkPrograms = new List<string>();
```

So you are erasing the old one.  Make a method of getting the list so far, if is null or empty then create a new one.  Otherwise don't or you'll empty what you have so far.

Update:  You can try this:

```
List<string> bookmarkPrograms = (List<string>)Session["BookmarkProgram"] == null ? new List<string>():(List<string>)Session["BookmarkProgram"];
```

For checking if the value exists already then:

```
if (bookmarkPrograms.Any(c=>c.Equals(ProgramID)){//don't add}
```

The inside expression returns a boolean that is true when a value inside the list equals what you are comparing. This example asumes ProgramID is a string. As they are string you might want to add trim() and tolower() but doesn't seems like in this case a blank space might accidentally be added... or that casing might affect. Since this returns true for when it exists, add a `!` in front of it so it adds to the list when it doesn't exists.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I have to add some thing like:
if (bookmarkPrograms == null)
             bookmarkPrograms = new List<string>();
into my code for creating new List at the first time and keep adding more string into it if it's the second time.

Comment: I updated with another suggestion for doing that logic in one line

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just figured out and updated my code in #1 post.Now it transfers all programID whenever user click on that button, but problem is it keep adding the string into the list,even though that programID existed in list already.Do you know how to check the value inside the list??

Comment: how about adding just the last one? would that work?  Anyway, to check if something exists, you get the value you would add to the list, then you get the list, and then you ask bookmarkPrograms.Any(c=>c.equals(stringProgramID)). I'll update and explain better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up with the code like this and it worked well:

        if (bookmarkPrograms == null)
            bookmarkPrograms = new List<string>();
        
        if (bookmarkPrograms.Any(c => c.Equals(stringProgramID)))
        {
            FormMessage.Text = "You bookmarked this program already";
        }
        else
        {
            bookmarkPrograms.Add(stringProgramID);
        }
        Session["BookmarkProgram"] = bookmarkPrograms;

Answer (score 1):

Just want to post the whole solution for someone need it in the future:

```
 protected void btnBookmark_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Button b = (Button)sender;      
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
    var ProgramID = row.FindControl("lblProgramID") as Label;
    string stringProgramID = ProgramID.Text;      
    List<string> bookmarkPrograms = (List<string>)Session["BookmarkProgram"];
    if (bookmarkPrograms == null)
        bookmarkPrograms = new List<string>();


    if (bookmarkPrograms.Any(c => c.Equals(stringProgramID)))
    {
        FormMessage.Text = "You bookmarked this program already";
    }
    else
    {
        bookmarkPrograms.Add(stringProgramID);
    }
    Session["BookmarkProgram"] = bookmarkPrograms;




}
```